# Can't resolve 'font-path(%22bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot%22'

Tags: css, fonts, sass, bootstrap-4, angular6

**Scenario :**

- Getting error after migrating from Angular 2 to 6.
- Used angular-cli to create a new project and replaced its source with
  mine.
- While running ng serve, i get the error detailed below :-

**Error :**
[image: Error in ng serve]
Overall there are 6 errors. Following is the app.scss file :-

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
@import "bootstrap-checkbox.scss";
// @import "forms.scss";
// @import "main.scss";
@import "bootstrap-and-customizations.scss";
@import 'old.scss';
@import 'forms.scss';
@import "dashboard.scss";
```

Comment: @if is in scss instead of normally if

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. Can you please be elaborate? Besides, the if(..) is in "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap" which is third party file.

Comment: Your error says csssyntax error, so i thought may be its the @if error, i havent looked in details, please check for your syntax, or any missing dependencies. For scss synatx refer : http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Comment: Yeah, i have updated all dependencies or atleast what i could understand in the package.json file. All i have coded is the @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"; which gives the error.

Comment: i dont know, error is saying that its unable to resolve the font-path provided ie with with `src: url (path)`. see for the path, see if the font is present on the specified path.

Comment: As you suggested, i downloaded this file :- glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot and placed it in ~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/ folder although in Angular 2, it never existed and bootstrap was working fine. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import like this

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```